# mysql + php encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I know there were plenty of questions like this but I am creating the new one because to my point of view it is specific to each situation.

So, my page is displayed in `UTF-8` format. The data is taken from mySQL that has `utf8_unicode_ci collation`. The data I am displaying is the string - `1  Bröllops-Festkläder`.

There are some unicode characters in here and they should display fine but they do not. On my page these are just a bunch of hieroglyphs.

Now, the interesting situation:

I am using phpMyAdmin to keep track of what is happening in the database. The website has the ability to import CSV documents containing customer data and modify each customer individually. If I import CSV document containing these characters they are written to the database, readable in phpMyAdmin and not readable on my page. If I use my script to modify the customer information and I type those characters from the browser, the it is vice versa - they are readable on the page and they are not readable in phpMyAdmin, so clearly the encoding is different. I spent ages figuring out the right combination and I could not.

**UPDATE**: Deceze posted a link below that I copy here to make it more noticeable. I am sure this will save hours and days to many people facing similar issues - [Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Please add a sscce or a link to your website.

Comment: All explained in-depth here: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze, while ago that helped me understand lots of things. Thank you for writing it.

Comment: Stefan, I am afraid it is not possible as this is a backend of a functional CRM. Deceze, thank for sharing the link. I will read it through

Comment: You should probably set the connection charset with mysql_set_charset. @deceze great article

Comment: Deceze, great article. WebnetMobile.com posted the solution below but if one checks the link you shared it would be really easy to figure the problem out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're couple of things that got involved here. If your database encoding is fine and html encoding is fine and you still see artefact, it's most likely your db connection is not using same encoding, thus leading to data corruption. If you connect by hand, you can easily enforce utf encoding, by doing query `SET NAMES UTF8` as very first thing after you `connect()` to your database. It is sufficient to do this only once per connection.

EDIT: one important note though - depending on how you put your data to the DB, your database content may require fixing as it can be corrupted if you put it via broken connection. So, if anyone is facing the same issue - once you set all things up, ensure you are checking on **fresh** data set, or you may still see things incorrectly, even all is now fine.

Comment: Don't query "SET NAMES", use `mysql_set_charset`.

Comment: In PDO variation this is $db = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME", "LOGIN", "PASS",
   array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8')
 );

Comment: Don't use mysql_* extension. Use mysqli_* :) Anyway, my answer is - beside DB schema and website encoding, there's db link that can also wreck your data. It's not obvious for many people. The way you address this is irrelevant, and depends on used libraries/drivers. If you'd be using Zend Framework for example, you should add `resources.db.params.charset = UTF8` to your application.ini file instead